Horizontal line in xmode=log plot
Per the title, my question is the exact inverse of this post.
I.e., given a plot with xmode=log, how can I draw a horizontal line at a specific y coord? Following this answer on the above question, I tried:
\draw (0,1.2 |- current axis.west) -- (0,1.2 |-
        current axis.east);

But this didn't work.

\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmode=log,
xmin=1, xmax=1000,
ymin=0, ymax=5,
]
\draw[red] (0,1.2 -|current axis.west) -- (0,1.2 -|current axis.east);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


It could also be done with a plot, if one for some reason wish that:
\addplot[
green, samples=2, forget plot,
domain=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},
]{1.2};


A very simple answer to this problem:
\addplot [domain=0.001:10,
    very thick,
    dashed,
    purple,
]{1.2};

Ensure the lower bound of the domain is >0, given you're working in log.

It would be nice to add samples=2 to avoid the line being chopped up into pieces. -larger file size, longer compile time, risk of viewer artefacts.
